# Better algorithm to riffle shuffle (or interleave) multiple lists of varying lengths

Tags: python, algorithm, language-agnostic, shuffle

I like to watch my favorite TV shows on the go.  I have all episodes of each show I'm following in my playlist.  Not all shows consist of the same number of episodes.  Unlike some who prefer marathons, I like to interleave episodes of one show with those of another.

For example, if I have a show called ABC with 2 episodes, and a show called XYZ with 4 episodes, I would like my playlist to look like:

```
XYZe1.mp4
ABCe1.mp4
XYZe2.mp4
XYZe3.mp4
ABCe2.mp4
XYZe4.mp4
```

One way to generate this interleaved playlist is to represent each show as a list of episodes and perform a riffle shuffle on all shows.  One could write a function that would compute, for each episode, its position on a unit-time interval (between 0.0 and 1.0 exclusive, 0.0 being beginning of season, 1.0 being end of season), then sort all episodes according to their position.

I wrote the following simple function in Python 2.7 to perform an in-shuffle:

```
def riffle_shuffle(piles_list):
    scored_pile = ((((item_position + 0.5) / len(pile), len(piles_list) - pile_position), item) for pile_position, pile in enumerate(piles_list) for item_position, item in enumerate(pile))
    shuffled_pile = [item for score, item in sorted(scored_pile)]
    return shuffled_pile
```

To get the playlist for the above example, I simply need to call:

```
riffle_shuffle([['ABCe1.mp4', 'ABCe2.mp4'], ['XYZe1.mp4', 'XYZe2.mp4', 'XYZe3.mp4', 'XYZe4.mp4']])
```

This works fairly well most of the time.  However, there are cases where results are non-optimal--two adjacent entries in the playlist are episodes from the same show.  For example:

```
>>> riffle_shuffle([['ABCe1', 'ABCe2'], ['LMNe1', 'LMNe2', 'LMNe3'], ['XYZe1', 'XYZe2', 'XYZe3', 'XYZe4', 'XYZe5']])
['XYZe1', 'LMNe1', 'ABCe1', 'XYZe2', 'XYZe3', 'LMNe2', 'XYZe4', 'ABCe2', 'LMNe3', 'XYZe5']
```

Notice that there are two episodes of 'XYZ' that appear side-by-side.  This situation can be fixed trivially (manually swap 'ABCe1' with 'XYZe2').

I am curious to know if there are better ways to interleave, or perform riffle shuffle, on multiple lists of varying lengths.  I would like to know if you have solutions that are simpler, more efficient, or just plain elegant.

---

Solution proposed by belisarius (thanks!):

```
import itertools
def riffle_shuffle_belisarius(piles_list):
    def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
        args = [iter(iterable)] * n
        return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
    if not piles_list:
        return []
    piles_list.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    width = len(piles_list[0])
    pile_iters_list = [iter(pile) for pile in piles_list]
    pile_sizes_list = [[pile_position] * len(pile) for pile_position, pile in enumerate(piles_list)]
    grouped_rows = grouper(width, itertools.chain.from_iterable(pile_sizes_list))
    grouped_columns = itertools.izip_longest(*grouped_rows)
    shuffled_pile = [pile_iters_list[position].next() for position in itertools.chain.from_iterable(grouped_columns) if position is not None]
    return shuffled_pile
```

Example run:

```
>>> riffle_shuffle_belisarius([['ABCe1', 'ABCe2'], ['LMNe1', 'LMNe2', 'LMNe3'], ['XYZe1', 'XYZe2', 'XYZe3', 'XYZe4', 'XYZe5']])
['XYZe1', 'LMNe1', 'XYZe2', 'LMNe2', 'XYZe3', 'LMNe3', 'XYZe4', 'ABCe1', 'XYZe5', 'ABCe2']
```

Comment: One problem is that if a series, say "XYZ", has much (two) more items than all the others, then it's impossible not have a side-by-side appearnce.

Comment: @ypercube:  Indeed, when one list has more than twice as many items as all other lists combined, there will be adjacent entries that belong to the same list.  However, this is usually not the case.  I'm looking for algorithms that do better in avoiding such adjacency problems.

Comment: Do you want it _random_? Do you accept a deterministic solution?

Comment: @belisarius:  Either is fine, so long as the items in each list (episodes of each show) appear in order in the final playlist.  I wouldn't want to watch episode 6 before episode 5. =)

Comment: @Adeel Like Star Wars :)

Comment: could you please post the expected output for this: riffle_shuffle([['ABCe1.mp4', 'ABCe2.mp4'], ['XYZe1.mp4', 'XYZe2.mp4', 'XYZe3.mp4', 'XYZe4.mp4', 'XYZe5.mp4', 'XYZe6.mp4', 'XYZe7.mp4']])...

Comment: @neurino:  One possible output: ['XYZe1.mp4', 'XYZe2.mp4', 'ABCe1.mp4', 'XYZe3.mp4', 'XYZe4.mp4', 'XYZe5.mp4', '
ABCe2.mp4', 'XYZe6.mp4', 'XYZe7.mp4']

Comment: Wasn't it supposed **not to have** ``two episodes of 'XYZ' that appear side-by-side``?

Comment: @neurino:  I'll clarify the question.  A good algorithm will not allow episodes from the same show to appear side-by-side.  However, if one show has way too many episodes (more than twice the number of all the other shows put together), then some episodes will, by necessity, appear side-by-side.

Comment: Nothing against belisarius solution but since it returns *always* the same identical results is it worth calling it __shuffle__? Is it what you asked seeing episodes *always* in the same combined order?

Comment: @neurino Thanks. You should revisit your ethics class.

Comment: @belisarius: you're welcome, I just pointed out that the word _shuffle_ in a media playing context like this is strictly related to randomness, thing that a deterministic solution definitively lacks, not an opinion, just a matter of fact. Sorry.

Comment: @neurino If you read the comments above yours, you'll see I asked the OP about that and he answered that he doesn't need randomness. Now you are trying to convince him that he does, marking as a fault in my answer something the OP already told us he doesn't care, and adding a plea in your answer asking for that one being accepted. It doesn't seem a transparent behavior to me.

Comment: @belisarius: I already read comments and apologize for what you call a _plea_, if not polite. All the rest of what I wrote stays unaffected to me. Cheers

Comment: Wouldn't a really simple solution be to grab one episode from the head of each list, in order? There's no need to mess around with fractional item positions.

Comment: Or alternately, sort your episodes by air date, since TV stations tend to interleave episodes of different shows anyway.

Comment: @Nick Johnson:  The simple solution would cause episodes of longer-running shows to clump together.  As for sorting by air dates, I'm afraid that information is lost to the winds. =)  The shows are ripped from my DVD collection.

Comment: @Adeel Only if all other shows had fewer episodes - in which case, there's not much you can do about that. Or are you hoping that if you have two shows with 2 episodes and one show with 4, you'll get something like [1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3] rather than [3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3]?

Comment: @Nick Johnson:  The former example, [1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3], yes.  I prefer that episodes of one show do not clump together.  In the latter example, two episodes of show 3 appear at the end, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A deterministic solution (ie not random)**

Sort your shows by decreasing number of episodes.

Select the biggest and arrange a matrix with the number of columns corresponding to the number of episodes of this one, filled in the following way:

```
A   A   A   A   A   A  <- First show consist of 6 episodes
B   B   B   B   C   C  <- Second and third show - 4 episodes each
C   C   D   D          <- Third show 2 episodes
```

Then collect by columns

```
{A,B,C}, {A,B,C}, {A,B,D}, {A,B,D}, {A,C}, {A,C}
```

Then Join

```
{A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,D,A,B,D,A,C,A,C}
```

And now assign sequential numbers

```
{A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2, A3, B3, D1, A4, B4, D2, A5, C3, A6, C4}
```

**Edit**

Your case

```
[['A'] * 2, ['L'] * 3, ['X'] * 5])

X  X  X  X  X
L  L  L  A  A

-> {X1, L1, X2, L2, X3, L3, X4, A1, X5, A2}
```

**Edit 2**

As no Python  here, perhaps a Mathematica code may be of some use:

```
l = {, , ,};                                 (* Prepare input *)
l[[1]] = {a, a, a, a, a, a};
l[[2]] = {b, b, b, b};
l[[3]] = {c, c, c, c};
l[[4]] = {d, d};
le = Length@First@l;

k = DeleteCases[                              (*Make the matrix*)
   Flatten@Transpose@Partition[Flatten[l], le, le, 1, {Null}], Null];

Table[r[i] = 1, {i, k}];                      (*init counters*)
ReplaceAll[#, x_ :> x[r[x]++]] & /@ k         (*assign numbers*)

->{a[1], b[1], c[1], a[2], b[2], c[2], a[3], b[3], d[1], a[4], b[4], 
   d[2], a[5], c[3], a[6], c[4]}
```

Comment: This algorithm definitely avoids adjacency problems.  It does, however, tend to clump episodes together.  I like it, overall. =)  I'll edit an implementation in Python into the question.  Thanks!

Comment: @Adeel You may get a family of different results using this same algo by choosing the number of colums greater than the number of episodes of the biggest show (but less than half the TOTAL number of episodes of all shows added up)

Answer (score 1):

My try:

```
program, play = [['ABCe1.mp4', 'ABCe2.mp4'], 
                 ['XYZe1.mp4', 'XYZe2.mp4', 'XYZe3.mp4', 'XYZe4.mp4', 
                  'XYZe5.mp4', 'XYZe6.mp4', 'XYZe7.mp4'],
                 ['OTHERe1.mp4', 'OTHERe2.mp4']], []
start_part = 3
while any(program):
    m = max(program, key = len)
    if (len(play) >1 and 
        play[-1][:start_part] != m[0][:start_part] and 
        play[-2].startswith(play[-1][:start_part])):
        play.insert(-1, m.pop(0))
    else:
        play.append(m.pop(0))

print play
```

Comment: I see that your algorithm is popping items from the longest remaining list until they're all gone.  Very nice.  Thanks!

Comment: At least it is simple. Not sure it always works correctly, if the longest one is much longer, fixed little to not mix up the order but first take parts from longest in order.

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure true shuffle i.e. a different result each time, with no contiguous items as much as possible.

The one you ask probably could return a few (1, 2) results limited by your requests.

```
from random import choice, randint
from operator import add

def randpop(playlists):
    pl = choice(playlists)
    el = pl.pop(randint(0, len(pl) -1))
    return pl, el

def shuffle(playlists):
    curr_pl = None
    while any(playlists):
        try:
            curr_pl, el = randpop([pl for pl in playlists if pl and pl != curr_pl])
        except IndexError:
            break
        else:
            yield el
    for el in reduce(add, playlists):
        yield el
    raise StopIteration

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sample = [
        'A1 A2 A3 A4'.split(),
        'B1 B2 B3 B4 B5'.split(),
        'X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6'.split()
        ]
    for el in shuffle(sample):
        print(el)
```

*Edit:*

Given episodes order is mandatory just simplify `randpop` function:

```
def randpop(playlists):
    pl = choice(playlists)
    el = pl.pop(0)
    return pl, el
```

Comment: Interesting thought.  However, due to random choice of episodes, often a recent episode of one show appears before a past episode of the same show.  All episodes of the same show need to appear in order in the final playlist.  I may have been vague about this.  However, I have edited my question in order to clarify this point.  Thanks.

Comment: As I wrote I won't deal with episodes ordering but it's quite easy to swap between recent and past in `list(shuffle(sample))`

Comment: You're welcome, please consider accepting my answer if you find it appropriate. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This would ensure that there is at least 1 and no more than 2 other episodes between two successive episodes of a show:

- While there are more than 3 shows, chain two shortest (i.e. having least episodes) shows together end-to-end.
- Let A be the longest show and B and C the other two.
- If B is shorter than A, pad it with `None`'s at the end
- If C is shorter than A, pad it with `None`'s at the beginning
- Shuffled playlist is `[x for x in itertools.chain(zip(A,B,C)) if x is not None]`